# How can I create a relationship between two random nodes based on parent node?

Tags: neo4j

I am working on a PoC for my company in an effort to move towards a graph database to leverage some relationship analysis benefits from using graph databases.

I've created a dataset as follows:

```
foreach (x in range(1,1400) | create (:District {name: "District " + x, id: "district-" + x}))
foreach (x in range(1,10000) | create (:School {name: "School " + x, id: "school-" + x}))
foreach (x in range(1,50000) | create (:Teacher {name: "Teacher " + x, id: "teacher-" + x}))
foreach (x in range(1,50000) | create (:Class {name: "Class " + x, id: "class-" + x}))
```

I've started creating the basic relationships with these queries:

*Create School -> District*

```
match (s: School)
match (d: District)
with collect (distinct s) as school, collect (distinct d) as districts

foreach (school in schools |
    foreach (district in [districts[toInteger(rand()*size(districts))]] |
        create unique (school)-[:belongs_to]->(district)
        )
    )
```

*Create Class -> School*

```
match (c:Class)
match (s:School)
with collect (distinct c) as classes, collect (distinct s) as schools

foreach (class in classes |
    foreach (school in [schools[toInteger(rand()*size(schools))]] |
        create unique (class)<-[:has]-(school)
        )
    )
```

*Create Teacher -> School*

```
match (t:Teacher)
match (s:School)
with collect (distinct t) as teachers, collect (distinct s) as schools

foreach (teacher in teachers |
    foreach (school in [schools[toInteger(rand()*size(schools))]] |
        create unique (teacher)-[:teachers_at]->(school)
        )
    )
```

The problem I am currently facing is this: I need to take each Teacher and assign it to 0-2 classes at random, but only for classes that belong to the school that that teacher teaches at. I've tried putting `MATCH` statements inside of the `FOREACH` blocks, but that is against the rules for Cypher queries.

I am looking for suggestions on creating this specific query.

> Note: As an aside, I am going to have to do this process again for a group of 250,000 students (randomly assign to a school, then randomly assign to 0-4 classes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select a pattern from the teachers to the schools. Then from school to the classes. And then randomly sort classes, and then use the limit:

```
MATCH (teacher:Teacher) WITH teacher
MATCH (teacher)-[:teachers_at]->(:School)-[:has]->(class:Class)
WITH teacher, 
     class ORDER BY RAND()
WITH teacher, 
     collect(class)[0..toInteger(rand()*3)] as classes
UNWIND classes as class
CREATE (teacher)-[:has_class]->(class)
```

Comment: This gives me an error:

    `Invalid input 'l': expected 'o/O', 'r/R' or 'a/A' (line 3, column 16 (offset: 114))
     DISTINCT class `
 Not sure why or how to fix this.

Comment: Changing this: `UNWIND classes as class CREATE (teacher)-[:has_class]->(class)` to this `UNWIND classes as c CREATE (teacher)-[:has_class]->(c)` appears to work. Not sure if there is an issue with using `class` in multiple parts, but it would not work originally.

Comment: One other thing I just realized is that this always attaches a teacher to a class. I can live with that, since this gets me to 95% of my problem solution.